# Changing Themes In Codeigniter

Tags: php, themes, codeigniter-2

Iam deveolping a site with adddition fetaure chening the themes of user side.For this i created a library .I wrote  a function in that library to load header.php page.

This is my library code:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class CI_theme_lib {
        public $theme_dir       = "themes/winter";
        public $header_page     = "header.php";

        public function get_header($header = ""){
            $dir = $this->theme_dir;
            $hdr = $this->header_page;
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            $string = $this->CI->load->view($dir.'/'.$hdr, '', true);
            return $string;

        }

    }
?>
```

In themes/winter is the my theme folder i want to apply.And i craeted a controller to view the theme:
Controller code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class test extends CI_Controller {

    public  function  __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('theme_lib'));
    }
    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('themes/winter/index');
    }
    }
?>
```

And in themes/winter/index.php code:

```
<?php
    echo $res = $this->theme_lib->get_header();
?>
```

In header.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>title</title>
</head>
```

So when i used this code i got an error message:

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: themes/winter/header.php
```

The `themes` in the root folder.
So how can i load a view page from root folder directory not from view directory?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** you can't. You can't because, to make things cleaner, the "system" paths are meant to be fixed, so that you always have models in the models folder, views in the views folder, etc. and therefore your structure will alwasy be regular and practical. Imagine you're going to mantain this app some months from now, when you need to change something in a view: where was it? Did I put it in thew views folder or somewhere else? themes? custom views? whatever views?

Keeping things strictly separated helps insure your application will be coherent, and easily mantained from whoever looks at the code after you. Even if that is you yourself, because it's easy to forget what you did when, even in your own code.

**Long answer (solutions included):** well, actually this might be shorted than the above :), but if you go to line 130 in the system/core/loader.php file (at least in version 2.1.0; anyway, it's the Loader class constructor), you'll see this:

```
    $this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH.'views/'  => TRUE);
```

which means your view will always be preceded by the hardcoded path to the view folder.

***Solutions?***

**[1]** You can remove the 'view/' part, but that would mean you need:

1. to rewrite each view you link through the `view()` method and prepend it with `view/`, or your app will irremediably broke down;
2. you don't have to upgrade your CI, or if you do, you'll have to remember to change things again, or else another dramatical broked down will happen.

**[2]** Another thing you can do is create another path, like, for example,

```
    $this->_ci_themes_paths = array(APPPATH.'themes/'=> TRUE);
```

and then create a method analogue to the `view()` method of the loader class (call it `themes()` method if you like), which will work the exact same way (buffering included) so that you'll have the ability to call

```
$this->load->themes('path/to/theme')
```

in your controller and have your themes loaded, while preserving the ability to load view. I'll definitely go for this solution, among the two. But still you'll need either not to upgrade the loader class, or to add the changes when you do that. But you won't break any core functionality this way, at least.

**Bonus answer for the practical people:** why not just create a `themes` folder inside the `view` folder, and put all your themes there? easy, clean, and hassle-free :)

Comment: I created this code in loader.php page `$this->_ci_themes_paths = array(APPPATH.'themes/'=> TRUE);` and `public function theme($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
 {
  return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_theme' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
 }`.Then i load the theme page as in controller `$this->load->theme('themes/winter/index');` But i got an error message `An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: .php
`.What is the error in my code?